# Using COMSOL simulation on Global Optimization Toolbox of MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, livelink, comsol

I want to use COMSOL simulation on Global Optimization Toolbox of MATLAB.

I tried to optimize control point of bezier curve (as design variables) in COMSOL model by using Genetic Algorithm (Global Optimization Toolbox of MATLAB).
So I tried to use LiveLink for MATLAB and Grobal Optimization Toolbox.

Then, MATLAB returned this error "Undefined variable "ModelUtil".

"main.m"(excerpt)
〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜
gamultiobj(@evaluation,nvars,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,intcon,options)
〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜

"evaluation.m"(excerpt)
function obj = evaluation(x);  %%% x is control point of bezier curve, obj is objective value

〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜
model = ModelUtil.create('Model');
〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜

I expected that I can do gamultiobj successfully.

Parallel computing option : true
I attach import com.comsol.model.* and import com.comsol.model.util.* and addpath of mli definitely.
Moreover I do mphstart with parfor (I confirm that mphstart is completed because simply calculation with COMSOL is completed).